# Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController Initializes in a bad state

Tags: c#, .net-core, joystick

I have a WPF dotnetCore3.1 Desktop application. In part, it uses a joystick to control an RS232 serial device. When a joystick is plugged in, the user can select it from a dropdown, then the software begins polling it, averaging it, and sending controls to the serial device. This uses Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController

Selecting from the dropdown causes this initializer

```
private void UpdateController()
{
    if (selectedController != null)
    {
        buttonStates = new bool[selectedController.ButtonCount];
        axisPositions = new double[selectedController.AxisCount];
        switchpositions = new GameControllerSwitchPosition[selectedController.SwitchCount];
        selectedController.GetCurrentReading(buttonStates, switchpositions, axisPositions);
    }
    else
    {
        buttonStates = Array.Empty<bool>();
        axisPositions = Array.Empty<double>();
        switchpositions = Array.Empty<GameControllerSwitchPosition>();
    }
}
```

The polling looks like this

```
private async void ControlAsync()
{
    // If axiscount < 2 then don't bother
    if (selectedController != null && selectedController.AxisCount > 1)
    {
        selectedController.GetCurrentReading(buttonStates, switchpositions, axisPositions);
        controlBuffer[0] += axisPositions[0];
        controlBuffer[1] += axisPositions[1];
        // Debug.WriteLine($"Controller: {axisPositions[0]}, {axisPositions[1]}");
    }

    // 0.5 is the neutral position
    else
    {
        controlBuffer[0] += 0.5;
        controlBuffer[1] += 0.5;
    }

    if (++controlCounter == controlCount)
    {
        controlCounter = 0;
        PositionerController.PanAxisPositon = controlBuffer[0] / controlCount;
        PositionerController.TiltAxisPositon = controlBuffer[1] / controlCount;

        controlBuffer[0] = 0;
        controlBuffer[1] = 0;

        await PositionerController.Control().ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is joysticks often come up reporting (0.0, 0.0) (full down left), regardless of where they are, while the neutral position is (0.5, 0.5). This will not update correctly unless and until the joystick is moved, which means that the serial device, a physical device, will take off on the user.
I have not been able to come up with a reliable way to fix this. I had some catches that sort of worked, e.g., locking the input until something other than 0,0 is seen, but it seems like there should be a cleaner / more standard way to do this.

This does not seem to be specific to the Windows.Gaming.Imput API, since this same problem comes up on another project where we read the joystick with embedded C firmware.

Comment: Then that would imply the joystick itself is reporting incorrect information, which no API can do anything about.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I was hoping there was a query or something I was supposed to send to the joystick to wake it up, rather than it waiting for somebody to move it to wake it up.